# How to return 401 status in Filter if attemptAuthentication is not successful

Tags: spring-security, exception, jwt

I'm trying to override `attemptAuthentication` method in `class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`
but it returns 500 status in case when login and password are incorrect. How to return 401?

```
 @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
                                                HttpServletResponse res) throws AuthenticationException {
        try {
            ApplicationUser creds = new ObjectMapper()
                    .readValue(req.getInputStream(), ApplicationUser.class);

            return authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                            creds.getUsername(),
                            creds.getPassword(),
                            new ArrayList<>())
            );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the exception class

```
}catch (IOException e){
```

makes it return 401. But why??

Answer (score 0):

It's the AuthenticationException that makes it return 401. If you catch Exception, it will catch AuthenticationException as well.

Comment: Removing is impossible because superclass doesn't support my specific IOException. My own catch clause for AuthenticationException would work, but why to do it if I can just change `Exception` on `IOException`. Thus when AuthenticationException occurs it goes further up. Now I undestand why.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that you needed to catch IOException. Yes, then it's the correct way. I'll remove that part from my answer.